# Ant task to build a MANIFEST.MF only

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ant, build, manifest

I am using IntelliJ to do JavaEE applications development. Artefacts include ****.gar (Coherence application), about 5 of *****.ear(EJB applications and web applications).

In my understanding, ant was used to build application jar, war,ear etc. But I am not plan to use ant to build or rebuild my applications as IntelliJ will do it by their own way.

What Im trying now? I am trying to use ant to create a MANIFEST.MF file and put it into my application src/META-INF/ when I build or rebuild my JavaEE artifacts. As IntelliJ provide a way to execute some Pre-processing or Post-processing ant task to accompany with IntelliJ build process.

I tried to find some example ant build code such as: build.xml over Internet. Unfortunately, they are all talking about create a jar/ear/war or some thing else that include a MANIFEST.MF as well.

My question is: Is there way to create a single MANIFEST.MF only by ant, if it is, please share that build.xml!

Lots thanks!

**After get advice from friend @Santosh who commented my thread. I got it works fine now.**

XML file example as:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="OzsscJPACoherence" basedir=".">

  <property name="projectName" value="OzsscJPACoherence" />
  <property name="libsSrc" value="libs"/>
  <property name="srcDir" value="../../src"/>
  <property name="artDir" value="../../../out/artifacts"/>
  <property name="distDir" value="${artDir}/OzsscJPACoherence_jar"/>
  <property name="build" value="build"/>
  <property name="classes" value="build/classes"/>
  <property name="jar" value="build/jar"/>
  <property name="libs" value="build/libs"/>
  <property name="version" value="2.5"/>

  <tstamp>
    <format property="TODAY" pattern="yyMMdd-HHmmss"  locale="en,AU" />
  </tstamp>

  <path id="classpath">
    <fileset dir="${libsSrc}" includes="*.jar"/>
  </path>

  <target name="jpacoh">
    <mkdir dir="${distDir}/META-INF" />
    <manifest file="${distDir}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF">
        <attribute name="Manifest-Version" value="1.0"/>
        <attribute name="Extension-List" value="coherence active-cache"/>
        <attribute name="coherence-Extension-Name" value="coherence"/>
        <attribute name="active-cache-Extension-Name" value="active-cache"/>
        <attribute name="Built-By" value="${user.name}"/>
        <attribute name="Specification-Title" value="${projectName}"/>
        <attribute name="Specification-Version" value="${version}"/>
        <attribute name="Specification-Vendor" value="StorageWay Australia"/>
        <attribute name="Implementation-Title" value="${projectName}"/>
        <attribute name="Implementation-Version" value="${version} ${TODAY}"/>
        <attribute name="Implementation-Vendor" value="StorageWay Australia"/>

    </manifest>
    <jar manifest="${distDir}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF" jarfile="${distDir}/OzsscJPACoherence.jar"/>
  </target>

</project>
```

And add ant task to related module as pre-processing task, rebuild artifact. MANIFEST.MF was created properly.

Hope this thread will help any one else in the same situation.

Thanks you guys help!

Answer (score 1):

```
<target name="dist" depends="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${dist}/lib" />
       <manifest file="${build}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF">
          <attribute name="Class-Path" value="MyGame.jar" />
       <attribute name="Main-Class" value="game.Game"/>  
   </manifest>
  <jar manifest="${build}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF" jarfile="${dist}/lib/MyGame.jar" basedir="${build}" />

</target>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I will try it.